# Slightly Distorted Bitmaps on some Android Devices

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap

I have a problem that occurs on some displays (HTC Hero, Motorola Defy, HVGA emulator) where some bitmaps are distorted in a peculiar way: The image apparently is shifted by one or two pixels, e.g. to the left, and the resulting gap on the right side is filled by duplicating pixels from the right border of the bitmap. I use pre-computed LDPI/MDPI/HDPI versions of these bitmaps, e.g. a notification icon that fits the specs for notification icons.

I attached two images that show the effect. Please note: even though it might appear that the bitmap is tiled, this is not the case, other images consistently show that the pixels are not wrapped around but duplicated/stretched.

[image: Original notification icon]
[image: Distorged notification icon in emulator]

Has anybody ever had a similar problem?

Thanks in advance for any clues that could help me solve this issue,

Arne

Comment: It may be but in Android's resizing code. In such case, you may fill in bug report to Android devs.
But, is Motorola Defy LDPI device with its 480x854 screen?

Comment: @mice You're right, of course, the Defy's display is not LDPI - thanks for the correction.